# Thymeleaf+spring, how to display image from local disc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Question: Hi, I have such a problem and don't know why it doesn't work. Analysing sources I think I don't have enough experience with this platform. Everything works properly but I want to display image on page.
The source of images is C:\Images directory where resides all my pictures from earlier algorithm implementation(Works properly sure).

There is my showimage.html script:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
<head>
<title>Script shows specified image</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/styles.css" th:href="@{/css/styles.css}"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="center">
        <h2><a th:href="@{/uploaded}">Click here to previous page where you can choose image to show</a></h2>
        <img src="C:/Images/1.jpg" alt="Didn't choosed the image">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify that is a file like: `<img src="file:///C:/Images/1.jpg">`